# How to determine the ideal defining $\overline{f(Z)}$ where $f$ is a regular map of affine variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a regular map of affine varieties. Let $Z$ be a closed set of $X$ and $I$ be the radical ideal defining $Z$. My question is how to determine the ideal defining $\overline{f(Z)}$? Can we have a concise formula involving $I$ to interpret it?

Comment: Atiyah & Macdonald, Ex 1.21: Let $\phi\colon A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(B)$. $\phi$ induces a mapping $\phi^*\colon Y\to X$. If $\mathfrak b$ is an ideal of $B$, then $\overline{\phi^*(V(\mathfrak b))}=V(\mathfrak b^c)$ where $\mathfrak b^c=\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak b)$ is the contraction of $\mathfrak b$.